# Msgbox not working in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I would like to filter data based on inputbox in my excel table. Then copy the data to another sheet. I used the code below. The code is almost working. But when there is no data available, I would like to show a message. In my code message1 and message2 both are not working.

```
Sub Findrpnumber()
    Call Clearoldrp

    Dim str1 As Variant
    Dim Tbl As ListObject
    Dim FiltRng As Range
    Dim RngArea As Range

    Set Tbl = Sheet2.ListObjects("DataTable")
    str1 = Application.InputBox("Select the RP Number")

    If str1 = False Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter one RP number", , "Find RP Data"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=str1
        For Each RngArea In Tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows
            If RngArea.Row > 1 Then
                If Not FiltRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set FiltRng = Application.Union(FiltRng, RngArea)
                Else
                    Set FiltRng = RngArea
                End If
            End If
        Next RngArea

        If Not FiltRng Is Nothing Then 'Filter range is not empty
            FiltRng.Copy Sheets("Chart").Range("A1")
            MsgBox "Data available on Chart Sheet" 'Message1
        Else
            MsgBox "RP Number not found" 'Message2
        End If
    End If
    Sheet2.ListObjects("DataTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems like your code never gets there. Could it be that the line `Exit Sub` is executed?

Comment: Does it make a difference using str1 = vbNullString instead of False, assuming you are testing for no entry in inputbox?

Comment: @E.Villiger i tried that , not working

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the condition str1=False and step through the program.

Comment: What do you mean by "message1 and message2 both are not working".  Does it crash and give an error message?  Or does it just go past those two lines without doing anything?  Do you have any `On Error` statements anywhere within your code, perhaps in whatever code calls `Findrpnumber`?

Comment: @QHarr vbNullString not working.

Comment: @YowE3K both the message are not displaying

Comment: Place an `On Error GoTo 0` immediately after the `Sub Findrpnumber` statement, and another one after `Call Clearoldrp`, and then run it and see what happens

Comment: I would set a breakpoint at the line `If Not FiltRng Is Nothing Then`. By pressing `F8` you can see clearly that how the code is executing.

Comment: @newacc2240 Thanks.I checked the problem is in this line - 'If Not FiltRng Is Nothing Then'

Comment: @E.Villiger I tried to create breapoint. But is not working. can you help me, where and what to add

Comment: To the left of this line 'If Not FiltRng Is Nothing Then' click on the grey vertical bar and a brown dot (break point should appear).

Comment: Put `On Error GoTo 0` after the second line of your code and run it to see where the error is coming from.

Comment: @Vityata I tried but no error is coming.

Comment: I created one new excel file and sample data. I tried the same code above. Now it is working perfectly, but it is not working on my original excel sheet. My program is strange. Whether i need to change any excel settings?